# when closing my tcp/ip socket connection thread is killing serial UART read thread in unix

Tags: linux, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, embedded-linux

I have two threads. One reads/writes serial UART and the other one reads/writes a server socket. When I close the client connected to the server its killing my other serial read/write thread. What could be the problem? See below for the code in question.

EDITED

The threads are created in the main function:

```
    /* client socket to write/read and close on if data there*/
    if( pthread_create(&t1 ,NULL,TCP_EventUploadHandler,NULL) < 0)
    {
            perror("could not create thread for TCP_EventUploadHandler");
            return 1;
    }
    /*create thread for main server*/
    if( pthread_create(&t2 ,NULL,command_handler,NULL) < 0)
    {
            perror("could not create thread for command handler");
            return 1;
    }
    /*create thread serial read*/
    if( pthread_create(&t3 ,NULL,ReadCard,NULL) < 0)
    {
            perror("could not create thread for Irish device");
            return 1;
    }
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    pthread_join(t3, NULL);
```

All 3 threads are continuously running. Whenever I close the other side of the TCP connection, my serial read is affected and stops reading and writing.

```
    void *command_handler(void *)
    {
    int opt = TRUE;
    int master_socket , addrlen , new_socket , client_socket[2] , max_clients = 2 , activity, i , valread , sd;
    int max_sd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    unsigned char buffer[9000];  //data buffer of 9K
    fd_set readfds;
    port_address();
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }
    if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( SERVPORT );

    if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    addrlen = sizeof(address);
    if(GUC_Debug_handle)
    puts("Waiting for connections ...");

    while(TRUE)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)
        {
            //socket descriptor
            sd = client_socket[i];
            if(sd > 0)
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
            if(sd > max_sd)
            max_sd = sd;
        }
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))
        {
            printf("select error");
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds))
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
            {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
            {
                if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                {
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;                  
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            sd = client_socket[i];

            if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds))
            {
                if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 9000)) == 0 || E_pipe_error == 1)
                {
                    E_pipe_error = 0;
                    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                    if(GUC_Debug_handle)
                    printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                    close(sd);
                    client_socket[i] = 0;

                }
                else 
                {
                    /*printf("\n");
                    for(i=0;i< valread;i++)
                    {
                        printf("%d ",buffer[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");*/
                    CMD_ProcessRecvdPacket(buffer,valread,sd);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return 0; 
/********************************************************/

    void *TCP_EventUploadHandler(void *)
    {
    struct sockaddr_in Event_clien_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    fd_set myset,readfds; 
    struct timeval tv;

    while(1)
    {
        Even_port_address();

        memset(buffer, '0',sizeof(buffer));
        if((sockfd_event = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
            return 0;
        } 

        server = gethostbyname(event_port);

        memset(&Event_clien_addr, '0', sizeof(Event_clien_addr)); 
        Event_clien_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        Event_clien_addr.sin_port = htons(CLIENTPORT);
        bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&Event_clien_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length); 
        //puts(event_port);
        //fcntl(sockfd_event, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

        if(TXN_PendingCount())
        {
            errno = 0;
            n = connect(sockfd_event, (struct sockaddr *)&Event_clien_addr, sizeof(Event_clien_addr));

            if(n <= 0)
            {   
                //printf("\nerror in  event: %d\n",errno);
                switch(errno)
                {
                    case EINPROGRESS:
                           tv.tv_sec = 20; 
                           tv.tv_usec = 0; 
                           FD_ZERO(&myset); 
                           FD_ZERO(&readfds);
                           FD_SET(sockfd_event, &myset); 
                           n = select(sockfd_event+1,&readfds, &myset, NULL, &tv);//  printf("\n\n");

                           if (n < 0 && errno != EINTR) 
                           { 
                              fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); 
                           }
                           else if (n > 0)
                           {    
                                printf("\nerror in  event: %d\n",errno);
                           }
                       break;

                       case 0:
                            printf("\nevent upload\n");
                            Send_read_event();
                            close(sockfd_event);
                            break;

                       case EISCONN : //56 Socket is already connected
                            printf("\nsocket is already connected\n");
                            Send_read_event();
                            close(sockfd_event);
                            break;
                       case ENOTCONN: //ENOTCONN 57 Socket is not connected
                            printf("\nSocket is not connected\n");
                            close(sockfd_event);
                            break;
                       case EALREADY: //37 Operation already in progress 
                            printf("\nOperation already in progress\n");
                            break;
                       case ETIMEDOUT: // 60 Connection timed out
                            printf("\nConnection timed out\n");
                            close(sockfd_event);
                            break; 
                       case ECONNREFUSED: // 61 Connection refused 
                            printf("\nConnection refused\n");
                            close(sockfd_event);
                            break;
                       case EHOSTDOWN: //64 Host is down
                            printf("\nHost is down\n");
                            close(sockfd_event);
                            break; 
                }
            }   
        }               
    }   
}
/*****************************************************/
void ReadCard(void)
{

for(;;){        
 char CMD_READ[14],str[14];
    unsigned char CMD[5]={0xA,0x02,0x01,0x9};
    memset(CMD_READ,0x00,sizeof(CMD_READ));
    memset(str,0x00,sizeof(str));
    //open_port();
    write(fd_serial_mifareread, CMD,4); 
    usleep(40*1000);
    read(fd_serial_mifareread, CMD_READ,14);
   procees_read(CMD_READ);
   }    
}
```

Comment: I would put my money on you having a bug.  Beyond that it is hard to tell without some code.

Comment: @Duck please find my edited question

Comment: What keeps `ReadCard` alive?  Is this a chopped version because this just just writes, sleeps, reads and ends.

Comment: no that is also continuously running I have missed out the loop while posting check the update on

Comment: as I found the thread status shows "R" its continues to be that state only till restart of that process again. how to make it run again or any other way